# Python Static Protocols VS Pyright messages

Tags: python, generics, protocols, pyright

I'm trying to learn how generics in Python work.

I got an example from Fluent Python book. It works fine, but I'd like to know if it is possible to make pyright checker satisfied?

```py
from typing import Protocol


class Repeatable[T](Protocol):
    def __mul__(self: T, repeat_count: int) -> T: 
        ...
        

def double[RT: Repeatable](x: RT) -> RT:
    return x * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(double(3))  # pyright error
    print(double('A'))  # pyright error
    print(double([1, 2]))  # pyright error
```

Thank You for Your help!

Comment: i thought i would use this initially because types are really helpful, but it makes python code complex and unreadable so defeats the purpose....

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. The type parameter `T` is used as a self-type, but is bound to the type instance itself. This is a logical contradiction; `T` cannot vary w.r.t. instances of `Repeatable`, since it is statically bound to precisely that instance. Instead, you could either use `typing.Self`, or move `T` to the `__mul__` scope.
2. The parameter of `__mul__` has a specific name, and can be used as either a  positional- or keyword-argument. So because it can be used as keyword arg, the name matters., i.e. `obj.__mul__(repeat_count=...)` is different from `obj.__mul__(birds_arent_real=...)`. Again, there are two possible solutions here; make it positional only (i.e. by placing a `/` after it), or "remove" the name (i.e. by prefixing it with `__`).

To illustrate, this is one of the possible solutions

```py
from typing import Protocol, Self


class Repeatable(Protocol):
    def __mul__(self, elmo_did_nothing_wrong: int, /) -> Self: 
        ...
        

def double[RT: Repeatable](x: RT) -> RT:
    return x * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(double(3))  # all good
    print(double('A'))  # still good
    print(double([1, 2]))  # don't eat the yellow snow, son.
```

See for yourself on the [pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAK4MYAxmADYA0UAygKYXABQrpFAhgM5dQBK9BPQ4wOAIwr0AFETAlyFAJQAuZlHVQAJvWBQA%2BnogBXCgaldGwGowhg9mpJr0o5AC1Ro9Ad3DplmFBgaAHpFKABaAD46S381DQSAOmT4hPVWbV1NMCMJegBtPgAVfwEhEXFJAF0pAA9SorCo-hLUqBB6GCMQFChaqAAqKAAmVmYkXQMUDgh6AygAXgWoAHIDCA5UAxXVBIQQVBgpbNzJKQBmRTCoAGIoDgoKKDQwME02-cPjnLypFYBBFZXdR3LgwJCPZ6vd57A6Bb6naT5ACMNGGVWBty0YBQK3wwnwMFc9CgcEYFDAXigXBcXiAA). It even works in pyright strict mode (and in expect mode it gets 5 stars for "through the fire and the flames" while speedrunning rainbow road).